# Is it possible to import a pfx file with VB

Tags: vb.net, pfx

Is it possible to import a pfx with VB.NET? I can with the command line, but that's definitely not preferable.

Edit: Using this code, I don't see my certificate under mmc snap-in. I don't get an exception or any errors during debugging.

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Try
        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\client.pfx", My.Resources.client, False)
        Dim sqlCert As New X509Certificate2(Environment.CurrentDirectory & "\client.pfx", "passwordhere")
        Dim store As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
        store.Add(sqlCert)
        store.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub

End Module
```

I am using `requireAdministrator`.

Solved: Changing `StoreLocation.LocalMachine` to `StoreLocation.CurrentUser` solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. That's what the [`X509Store`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148581(v=vs.110).aspx) class is for.

```
Dim yourCert As New X509Certificate2("C:\YourPath\cert.pfx", "YourPfxPasswordIfAny")
Dim store As New X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
store.Add(yourCert)
store.Close()
```

You'll need to run your program as an elevated administrator in this example since we are importing into the LocalMachine store.

All of the classes are in the `System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates` namespace.

Comment: Privileges is no problem. Ah, that's why I didn't get any results. I didn't know that X509 was for my problem.

Comment: According to the Certificates snap-in, I don't see my cert. I didn't get any errors while debugging either.

Comment: @TylerMontney where do you expect the certificate to be? The above code us putting it into the Local Machine \ Personal store. When you look in the MMC tree, does the top say "Current User" or "Local Machine"?

Comment: Hahaha you're absolutely right. It's installing for Local Machine, and I was viewing for user account. I definitely need more experience when dealing with certs... Changing StoreLocation to CurrentUser fixed it. Thank you for your help.